# react-html-parser white list for tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

i trying create a comments for my projects, and now I have mentation user.

I create a link to the profile of the user who was mentioned, and parsing with react html parser, but now there is an opportunity to write comments in html, but I don’t want that. now I cut off all html tags, and then add a link to the profile.

How i can render only link to profile and the rest of the tags as plain text?

Create link:

```
const createLink = comment => {
    const plainText = comment.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
    return plainText.replace(/@\[([^()]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)/g, '<a href=/user/$2>$1</a>');
  };
```

Link to user profile

```
<a href=/user/123abc>@nickname</a>
```

Raw data about user

```
[@nickname](123abc <----- it's id)
```

Call create link

```
{parse(createLink(text))}
```

I use react and typescript

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem
I just replace <> with < >